# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail addres

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is an hyphen in the domain name.

```
sendToEmail = "abc@domain-self.com";
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(UserName, sendToEmail, EmailSubject, "");
```

This Code throws error:

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

If there is no hyphen in the email then it works correctly.

How to resolve this?

Comment: What is the content of `UserName`? Because the code you show here will not throw that exception - hyphens are perfectly valid.

Comment: @DavidG Username is plain text "sbcindia".

Comment: That's not a valid email address, you need to fix that.

Comment: So to clarify, that parameter is the **from** email address. Perhaps you meant to have the `UserName` as part of the to address, which mean should use `new MailAddress("abc@domain-self.com", "sbcindia")`.

Comment: `"sbcindia"` is what's causing this exception. `"abc@domain-self.com"` is a valid mail address.

Comment: @DavidG Yes it got resolved by changing the Username. Thanks

Comment: OK, I'm voting to close as a typo then